# Showing the time left before an SQL event

Tags: sql, timer

I am developping a game in HTML/PHP where you have to wait an amount of time before the building is built.

***Exemple :***

- The player clicks on the button to upgrade Building1 which takes 300
  seconds to build.
- An SQL event is added at current timestamp +
  300seconds :

  ```
  CREATE EVENT building1 ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 300 SECOND DO

  UPDATE BUILDINGS
  SET BUILDING1LVL = BUILDING1LVL + 1
  WHERE USERID = '$USER';
  ```

Now i would like the user to have a timer on the Building1 item showing how many seconds/minutes/hours/days/weeks are left.

Right now i have : https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFwqr.png

With the timestamp of the beggining of the building and the timestamp of the end of the building stored in the database.

And i need : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rWi5.png

With the dark grey overlay moving in real time until the bottom when the build is complete.

The code i'm using :

The button where you click to upgrade a building :

```
<div id="upgrade_img" onclick="location.href='upgrade.php?id=1'"></div>
```

Code in upgrade.php :

```
<?php
/*
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION[identifiant])  
{  
    header('location: /index.php');  
    exit;  
}
*/
require "config.php";
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $idupgrade = $_GET['id'];
    $idupgrade = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $idupgrade);

    if (is_numeric($idupgrade))
    {
        $result = mysqli_query($link, "CREATE EVENT building1 ON SCHEDULE AT     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 20 SECOND DO UPDATE lands SET bat_bois = bat_bois +     1 WHERE id = 1;");
        if (!$result)
        {
            //error
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //error
    }
}
else
{
    //error
}
?>
```

Comment: You did not specify which client technology you are using: HTML + javascript? If so, please share the code you have, and add these tags to your question so experts in those areas will notice your question.

Comment: Yes this is really a client question - if you have the start and end times then really the question is how to display it.

Comment: Oh sorry. The game is using HTML and PHP. Javascript would work.

Comment: I updated the code. My previous host wouldn't let me use SQL EVENTS, it's now fixed.